# Align an ::after element at the end of a two-line text in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element, browser-bugs

I want to align an after element at the end of a text that runs over two lines.

This works in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can solve this?

The blue line should be right after the word headline, like "headline _".

```css
p.subtitle {
  color: #F94922;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

p.subtitle::after {
  content: "";
  background: #002C5A;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  right: -66px;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtitlewrap">
  <p class="subtitle">This is a long <br />headline</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this using absolute positioning to begin with? With that, you are losing any connection to the actual end of the text, and it becomes related to the bounding box the paragraph creates. `display: inline-block` and the position stuff removed completely, would be closer to a sensible approach to begin with, IMHO.

Comment: When the parent element is "position: relative", the inner element will align absolute to the parent. The parent is inline, so the end of the element is where the text ends.

Comment: @CBroe I saw you just edited your question. When i remove the "position: absolute", the element sticks to the left. https://jsfiddle.net/g63tefr5/1/

Comment: That’s because it is still `display:block`, I said make that `inline-block` (so that width & height can take effect, while it still behaves “inline”.)

Comment: Ohh! Thank you. That's it! (I stupidly set the parent element to inline block.)
This works -> https://jsfiddle.net/ya436zgo/